# c# newbie: if statement && with int

Tags: c#, if-statement

i'm crossing a problem in the code i made for the second Euler problem (sum of the even fibonacciresults until 4million.

i'm using an if statement with integers (also tried long, ...) and it sais the '&&' can not be used with int.
how can i fix this or did i make another mistake ?

tnx in advance

```
        int result = 3;
        int resultMinEen = 1;
        int resultMinTwee = 2;        

        for (int i = 1; i <= 4000000; i++)
        {
            if ((i % 2) == 0 && i = resultMinEen + resultMinTwee)
            {
                result += i;
                resultMinTwee = resultMinEen;
                resultMinEen = result;
            }
        }
```

Comment: == is to test equality, = is to instanciate a value. In if you can't use =

Comment: If you know == is for comparison (assuming you know it because of the part (i % 2)== 0) then what are you trying to do with i = rme + rmt?

Answer (score 7):

(i = resultMinEen + resultMinTwee) is what is going to return an integer. It is setting the value of i, which is the loop variable. If this is what you are intending to do then it is very bad practice and you should set a second, temporary variable inside the body of the if test and use that. If you are attempting to test that i is equal to resultMinEen + resultMinTwee, then make it == (comparison operator) instead of = (assignment operator).

Answer (score 0):

there is difference between = and == :)

```
 int result = 3;
    int resultMinEen = 1;
    int resultMinTwee = 2;



    for (int i = 1; i <= 4000000; i++)
    {
        if (((i % 2) == 0) && (i == resultMinEen + resultMinTwee))
        {
            result += i;
            resultMinTwee = resultMinEen;
            resultMinEen = result;
        }
    }
```